# web workers, Worker thread isn't executing code after being called

Tags: javascript, multithreading, backend, web-worker

I created a worker that implements the Astar algorithm using web workers.
The code in the main class is:

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const worker = new Worker("./astarA.js");
```

I then used it inside a method that's being called 30 times / second as follows.

```
worker.postMessage({ start: s, goal: g });

worker.onmessage = function (path) {
  this.hpath = path;
  console.log("path is ", path);
}; // aStar(s, g);
let ls = 0;
```

The code in the worker is as follows:

```
const { parentPort, workerData } = require("worker_threads");
parentPort.on("message", (message) => {
  let hpath = aStar(message.start, message.goal);

});
```

Thing is, this worker seems to be getting called correctly, but it only executes for what seems to be a very brief period of time, as in for example, the astar algorithm implementation has multiple loops within it, but they run once or twice only and stop completely, not because the algorithm is wrong, but because the entire 'thread' seems to stop executing?

Also for some reason I can't console.log() more than once when in the worker class and anytime i try to do more it just doesn't log the output and only displays the first console.log's output.

I'm using nodejs v16.17.0.